# SQL инъекция WordPress, wp admin

Tags: wordpress, sql-injection, login

Как в WordPress можно продемонстрировать SQL-инъекцию при входе в админ часть или при авторизации на сайте? Где можно изменить код, чтобы продемонстрировать эту уязвимость?

Comment: Вам это зачем? Я бы в хакеры пошёл, пусть меня научат? ))

Comment: Ребята из РосКомПозора уже нашли тебя по IP и едут

Comment: для демонстрация как работает sql injection

Comment: Ну и покажите на своём коде. В WP дыр нет. Вопрос звучит так, что вы хотите, чтобы вас научили, как сломать WP. Не то место выбрали.